# What is __N() in this statement std::__throw_out_of_range(__N("array::at"))?

Tags: c++, arrays, stdarray, outofrangeexception

I was looking at the definition of `at()` function from [array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00752_source.html) header file to clear some doubts. Here's the definition-

```cpp
reference                   //typedef for &value_type of array
at(size_type __n)           //size_type is typedef for size_t
{
    if (__n >= _Nm)        //_Nm is typedef for size of array
        std::__throw_out_of_range(__N("array::at"));   //what is __N(...) ?
    return _M_instance[__n];        //_M_instance[...] is variable of type std::array
}
```

So, what is that `N(...)` on the last third line? Or more specifically, what does it do?

Comment: It depends. Some development environments will let you right click on the N and go to its definition. I can't answer more fully without looking through your includes.

Comment: Some deep-dark implementation macro. I was doing what Tim suggested as he posted and it's lurking about 1/4 of the way into c++config.h.

Comment: @Tim I have provided link to the source if you want to look.

Comment: @avm it looks like Cory found the answer. I'm deferring to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [their source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/c%2B%2Bconfig#L644-L648)

```
// This marks string literals in header files to be extracted for eventual
// translation.  It is primarily used for messages in thrown exceptions; see
// src/functexcept.cc.  We use __N because the more traditional _N is used
// for something else under certain OSes (see BADNAMES).
#define __N(msgid)     (msgid)
```

Comment: To be clear, then, the macro isn't 'doing' anything much.

Comment: A curiosity here -- `std::at` is an identifier, not prose text. Are they really planning to translate it to other languages in the message?